# Getting data ID from the button in jQuery

Tags: jquery, events

I have a button that call a function like this:

```
<button onClick="editCategory('.$categories->id.')" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</button>
```

and in the button I have edit category like this:

```
function editCategory(id){
     alert('id')
}
```

when I hit the button I got this error in my console:

```
ReferenceError: editCategory is not defined onclick
```

What make this kind of errors? and is it possible to remove that function from the button so I can access it like this but still getting the value of id:

```
$( "#editCategory" ).click(function(event) {
     // how can I get the id in here?
});
```

for more info this button is inside DataTables Jquery plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try addind the categories id as data attribute on the html, also add the button `id="editCategory"` to attach the event to the button.

```
<button data-category="' . $categories->id . '" class="editCategory btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Edit</button>
```

And on the click event, retrieve the category id from the button:

```
   $( "button.editCategory" ).click(function(event) {
        var id = $(this).data('category');
        editCategory(id);
    });
```

You can also use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.editCategory',function(event) { 
   var id = $(this).data('category'); 
   editCategory(id);
});
```

Comment: i try to test your code in my program like this      var id = $(this).data('category');               console.log(id);

Comment: oh for more info that button is inside DataTables.

Comment: You didn't metion that. Do you have jQuery loaded? I updated the anwser to allowing attaching the event with a class selector since a id must be unique in the DOM and you are using datatables.

Comment: yes it loaded already. I'm sorry i never though that it will cause the problem but then when i try your answer and it show me nothing and then i realize maybe that one the cause.

Comment: still doesn't work, i try to alert and console log it but i got nothing. although in data-category i have some data

Comment: what happens if you run `$( "button.editCategory" )` on the console?

Comment: i got nothing. it seem it's not detecting any event.

Comment: Object lenght 0

Comment: strange, have you add the class to the button? Try `$( "button" )`

Comment: ah Sorry i clear browser cache and it give me 5 button class.

Comment: for `$( "button" )` or `$( "button.editCategory" )` ? Try add the javascript inside `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: for $( "button.editCategory" );  i already put in document ready function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159578/discussion-between-claudio-and-henra).